# Botkit and https secure endpoint, is a certificate mandatory?

Tags: https, slack-api, slack, botkit

I'm building a custom slack app with botkit framework and I'm trying to add a interaction button in my Bot/App.

I don't really catch one thing, as the botkit framework provides a way to have a webhook entry and setuped server to receive oauth requests and slack's requests for interactive buttons callbacks, does having a secured server with Https, certificate and all that stuff is mandatory for slack's API to perform POST requests on my server after hitting a interactive button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a valid and non-self-signed SSL certificate is required to receive inbound requests on your server when message buttons are clicked by users. The certificate is also required for a few other outbound operations performed by Slack, like slash command executions and the Events API.

While in development, many developers use a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to proxy their requests, though it's not really appropriate for production use.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications :D

Comment: Also to add to this, there are free and fairly easy to use tools that will enable you to use SSL in production.The Slack documentation points this out as well. [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/) are both great!